# Not able to get the number of days correctly

Tags: momentjs

I am using momentjs to try to get the difference in days between 2 dates but the days returned are not correct. The start date is 2021-04-05 and the end date is 2021-04-09 and it is returned 4 instead of 5.

I did a console log and this is what I get.

[image]

here is my code:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date())

const ed = moment(endDate)
const sd = moment(startDate)

console.log(ed) 
console.log(sd) 
    
<h6>Total Number of Days: {ed.diff(sd, 'days')}</h6>
```

Where did I get it wrongly? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got the difference and hope it will be useful to anyone. thanks

{Math.floor(( Date.parse(endDate) - Date.parse(startDate) ) / 86400000)}